# how to delete the <script> in the news I crawlered

Tags: javascript

Here is my code, when I execute it, there are some information which is from code of original website. They are included in the results.

```
enter code here
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
URLdict=dict()
pageNum=1
while pageNum<2:
    user_agent = 'Chrome/58.0(compatible;MSIE 5.5; Windows 10)'
    headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent}
if pageNum==0:
    response=urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.1905.com/list-p-catid-
221.html')
else:
    url = 'http://www.1905.com/list-p-catid-221.html' + '?
    refresh=1321407488&page=' + str(pageNum)
    request = urllib.request.Request(url,headers=headers)
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
first = response.read().decode('utf-8')
BSobj = BeautifulSoup(first, "html.parser")
for a in BSobj.findAll("a", href=True):
  if re.findall('/news/', a['href']):
     URLdict[a['href']] = a.get_text()
            #print(URLdict)
for link, title in URLdict.items():
 print(title, ":", link)
 ContentRequest = urllib.request.Request(link,headers=headers)
 ContentResponse = urllib.request.urlopen(ContentRequest)
 ContentHTMLText = ContentResponse.read().decode('utf-8')
 ContentBSobj = BeautifulSoup(ContentHTMLText, "html.parser")
 Content = ContentBSobj.find("div", {"class": "mod-content"})
 if Content is not None:
     print(Content.get_text())
pageNum=pageNum+1
```

I checked the original code,these information are from ,they are like these:

```
enter code here
var ATLASCONFIG = {
            id:"1197971",
            prevurl:"http:www.1905.com/news/20170704/1197970.shtml#p1",
            nexturl:"http:www.1905.com/news/20170704/1197970.shtml#p1",
            shareIframe:"http://www.1905.com/api/share2.php?....
        }
```

These information appeared in the results rather than my code. I can not send more than two links, so I deleted "//",I want to ask how to delete these,

Comment: Use `delete` to remove a property from an object.

Answer (score 0):

Use `delete` to remove a property from an object.

```js
var ATLASCONFIG = {
 id:"1197971",          
 prevurl:"http:www.1905.com/news/20170704/1197970.shtml#p1", 
 nexturl:"http:www.1905.com/news/20170704/1197970.shtml#p1",
 shareIframe:"http://www.1905.com/api/share2.php?...."
}

delete ATLASCONFIG["shareIframe"];
console.log(ATLASCONFIG);
```